# Como guardar Relacion hasMany y belongsTo

Tags: laravel-5

esta es mi pregunta, como puedo guardar la relacion entre estos dos modelos? Osea obtener el `id de la carrera` y guardarlo en mi modelo Materia en su correspondiente campo que es `carreras_id`

Modelo Materia

```
    public function carreras()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Carreras::class);
    }
```

y Modelo Carreras

```
    public function materias()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Materia::class);
    }
```

en mi controlador Materia para guardar la Materia lo hago de este modo

```
$materias = new Materia();
        $materias->nombre = $request->get('nombre');
        $materias->objetivoGeneral = $request->get('objetivoGeneral');
        $materias->creditos = $request->get('creditos');
        $materias->area_especialidad_id = $request->area_especialidad_id == 0 ? null : $request->area_especialidad_id;
        $materias->save(); 
        return redirect()->route('carreras.index');
```

Lo que no entiendo en esta parte es como guardar el `carreras_id` que esta en la tabla Materia para despues filtrar los datos que me arroje, alguna sugerencia?

Edito: En si lo que busco es guardar el id de la carrera en mi tabla Materia en el campo `carreras_id`

Osea quiero relacionar mi materia con la carrera correspondiente.

Comment: En tu formulario consultas las especialidades?, deberían estar en un select

Comment: La parte de las especialidades no es un problema ya que como dices consulto las especialidades, y despues guardo los datos de esa manera, en esa tabla Materia tengo carreras_id, en ese campo quiero agregar el id de la carrera a la que accedi

Comment: La cosa es saber como puedo acceder al id de la carrera y agregarla a la tabla Materia en el campo carreras_id

Comment: Pero es que deberías tener también un select para elegir la carrera a la que pertenece la materia y en el controller `$materias->carrera_id`

Comment: Creo que ya te entiendo porque lo que hago es acceder al metodo show de carreras y luego al metodo create de Materias, y no conozco algun metodo para hacer lo que intento

Comment: Si creas la Materia desde el show de Carreras, ahí ya tienes el id; solo debes pasarlo a la vista de crear Materia para enviarlo al controller.

Comment: ¿Al momento de querer registrar la materia deberías tener un select que despliegue los nombres de las especialidades y de ahi mandar el `id` ? al menos de ese modo lo entendí @CesarRomero

Comment: @Dohko19 en `area_especialidad_id` es donde quieres guardar el `id` de la carrera? @Aprendiz yo menciono carrera porque es lo que veo en su Model, siguiendo la estructura el esta hablando de `carrera_id`

Comment: cierto @CesarRomero entonces a lo que el dice especialidades en realidad se refiere a carreras y en lugar de especialidad_id sería como dices carrera_id cierto?

Comment: ammm no, en la parte de especialidad ese tema esta resuelto es mas como dice Cesar, tendria que pasar el ID a la vista create de materias, pero aqui es como puedo guardar este ID de carreras en la tabla materias que tiene un campo llamado carreras_id, entonces seria guardarlo mas o menos asi pero no estoy seguro (ya que lo he intentado) `$materias->carreras_id = $request->carreras_id;` o puedo hacerlo asi $materias->carreras->associate($materia)? esta ultima no estoy seguri

Comment: si se llama `carreras_id` debes asociar mejor tu Model https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse lo cual seria `public function carrera()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Carreras::class, 'carreras_id');
}` La nomenclatura de Laravel reconoce las palabras en ingles, en español se complica, así que mejor le indicas cual es exactamente el atributo asociado a la clase

Comment: Lo puse de ese modo ya que al intentar con carrera_id, laravel me marco que no encontraba `carreras_id` y decidi cambiar el nombre del campo, entonces ya solo me resta llevar el ID y guardarlo como lo hice con la especialidad, no?+

Comment: Si, en teoría si ya solo tendrías que guardar como especialidad, y luego podrás obtener la carrera a la que pertenece la materia. (si notas en la función que coloque esta `carrera()` en singular, porque de `$materia->carrera()` accedes a la carrera (una materia pertenece a una carrera)